# Assign Vue instance data to a non reactive variable

Tags: vue.js

I have a form that has a modal that I use to populate an array within the form. Every time the modal is submitted, I push the Vue object into an array that is on the main form. The problem I'm facing is that every item in the array is linked and when I edit one item, all the items in the array get edited.

```
data: {
  myForm: {
    form_element: null,
    my_array: [],
  },
  modalForm: {
    modalFormElement: null,
  },
},
methods: {
  addRow(){
    this.myForm.my_array.push(this.modalForm);
  },
},
```

Assigning this.modalForm to a variable first did not work.

Comment: Can you share your template code also.

Comment: `this.myForm.my_array.push([...this.modalForm])`

Comment: You need to clone `this.modalForm` before you push it to the array so that you are not storing the same object in the array multiple times. Maybe a deep clone.

Comment: @connexo wrong brackets I think. I'd go with `{...this.modalForm}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a reference issue. The modalForm object (i.e this.modalForm) references the same place in memory. When you push `this.modalForm` into the array, changing the value of a property of the object will change the rest. To prevent this issue, copy the modalForm object before pushing it to the array.

```js
data: {
  ...
  modalForm: {
    modalFormElement: null,
  },
},
methods: {
  addRow(){ //
    this.myForm.my_array.push({...this.modalForm}); // shallow clone the object using the es2015 spread syntax
  },
},
```

The [following](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript) are other ways to clone objects in JavaScript, but I will stick to the es2015 spread syntax in my example. For more on javascript references for objects, see [this](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)